# How can I change the width of each component in a UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

How can I change the width of each component in a `UIPickerView`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Implement `pickerView:widthForComponent:` method in picker's delegate and return appropriate width for each component from it. e.g.

```
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component{
      switch (component){
           case 0: 
                return 100.0f;
           case 1: 
                return 60.0f;
     }
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is (full function) return?

Comment: The Apple documentation is very clear: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html

Comment: here is updated response for Swift in iOS8: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943883/uipickerview-width-in-ios8-swift

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4 version:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    let w = pickerView.frame.size.width
    return component == 0 ? (2 / 3.0) * w : (1 / 3.0) * w
}
```

in this example:
2/3 of width for first component and 1/3 for the second

Using fixed values may be a bad idea, because of various screen sizes.