# UIPickerView Width in iOS8 Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, width, uipickerview

I simply can not find out how to get a width of a component on my UIPickerView.  It's not allowing something simple (Int) as it needs to be CGFloat.  What exactly do I put in the <#code#> section?

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    <#code#>
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: This method is used to set the width no to get the width

Comment: You should accept one of the answers given.

Answer (score 6):

That method doesn't "get a width of a component..." The picker view calls that method to ask you how wide a component should be.

Your method could be as simple as:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat 
{
  return CGFloat(25.0)
}
```

(or whatever width is appropriate for your picker view...)

You just need to cast the result to the exptected type.

Comment: Thank you!  I did mean set the width.  You knew the answer AND the question I wanted to ask.

Comment: If I've answered your question you should accept my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to return a width of a component is to use bounds.width:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat 
{
  return self.view.bounds.width / x
}
```

Where x would be a number of the components you desire to have in a PickerView.